# Query Azure Compute Quotas from .NET SDK

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

I am looking for examples of how to use the Azure .NET SDK to query for the current usage and remaining quotas for Compute resources (say Dsv3 vCPUs).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, we can use Azure .Net SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent` to list the usage of Microsoft.Comput resource in one Azure Subscription. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.fluent.computemanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet)

1. [Use Azure CLI to create a service pricipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)

```
 az login
 az ad sp create-for-rbac --name <ServicePrincipalName>
 az role assignment create --assignee <ServicePrincipalName> --role Contributor
```

2. Code

```
var tenantId = "<your tenant id>";
var clientId = "<your sp app id> ";
var clientSecret = "<your sp passowrd>";
var subscriptionId = "<your subscription id>";
AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                       clientId,
                       clientSecret,
                       tenantId,
                        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
RestClient restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                                  .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                                  .WithCredentials(credentials)
                                  .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                                  .Build();
ComputeManagementClientclient = new ComputeManagementClient(restClient);
client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

foreach (var s1 in await UsageOperationsExtensions.ListAsync(client.Usage, Region.AsiaSouthEast.Name)) {

                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + s1.Name.LocalizedValue +"\nUnit: "+ UsageInner.Unit + "\nCurrentValue: " + s1.CurrentValue + "\nLimit: " + s1.Limit);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
}
```

[image]

Comment: @kyuz0 If it is useful for you, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It may help more people who have similar issue.